# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' Issue

Tags: asp.net, oracle

When I run the application in asp.net,some error displays like below...What I can do? Can you please solve this issue?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies.The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)..
```

Oracle version is 2.112.2.0

Answer (score 0):

you just need to redirect the assembly to the current one in the web.config file as below :

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342"   culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.2.0.700" newVersion="4.112.3.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501896/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccessversion-9-2-0-700-culture-neu)**